# Return decoded text from the database

Tags: mysql, decode

I have a text in the database that looks like that:

```
69&lt;sup&gt;something&lt;/sup&gt;
```

And when I put it on a web page I see:

```
<sup>something</sup>
```

I want to know how do I return that data already decoded? So eventually when I'll go to the page source I'll see:

```
<sup>something</sup>
```

And NOT:

```
69&lt;sup&gt;something&lt;/sup&gt;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does "already decoded" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print the content using the decoder function

```
html_entity_decode($content_from_db);
```

Comment: Thanks that help. I'm using ASP.NET so its HttpUtility.HtmlDecode, but you pointed the direction.